# Why is this transform set in this Unity script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have been following this great tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxrKE2VKvmc

and at some point it does this for each target, it creates a gameObject ?

If you look at the code here:

```
private void SetupTargets(List<TrackableBehaviour> allTargets)
    {
        Debug.Log("Listing all Targets names:");

        foreach (TrackableBehaviour target in allTargets)
        {
            Debug.Log("Target's name:" + target.TrackableName);

            target.gameObject.transform.parent = transform;
            target.gameObject.name = target.TrackableName;

            target.gameObject.AddComponent<PlaneManager>();

            Debug.Log(target.TrackableName + " created!");
        }
    }
```

why this line of code ?

```
target.gameObject.transform.parent = transform;
```

If I comment it out it still works fine..

The full class code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
using System.Linq;

public class TargetManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public String mStartingMarkerDatabaseName = "";

    private List<TrackableBehaviour> mAllTargets = new List<TrackableBehaviour>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        VuforiaARController.Instance.RegisterVuforiaStartedCallback(onVuforiaStarted);
    }

    private void onDestroy()
    {
        VuforiaARController.Instance.UnregisterVuforiaStartedCallback(onVuforiaStarted);
    }

    private void onVuforiaStarted()
    {
        LoadDatabase(mStartingMarkerDatabaseName);
        mAllTargets = GetTargets();
        SetupTargets(mAllTargets);
    }

    private void LoadDatabase(string name)
    {
        ObjectTracker objectTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>();
        objectTracker.Stop();

        if (DataSet.Exists(name))
        {
            DataSet dataSet = objectTracker.CreateDataSet();
            dataSet.Load(name);
            objectTracker.ActivateDataSet(dataSet);
        }

        objectTracker.Start();
    }

    private List<TrackableBehaviour> GetTargets()
    {
        List<TrackableBehaviour> allTrackables = new List<TrackableBehaviour>();

        allTrackables = TrackerManager.Instance.GetStateManager().GetTrackableBehaviours().ToList();

        return allTrackables;
    }

    private void SetupTargets(List<TrackableBehaviour> allTargets)
    {
        Debug.Log("Listing all Targets names:");

        foreach (TrackableBehaviour target in allTargets)
        {
            Debug.Log("Target's name:" + target.TrackableName);

            target.gameObject.transform.parent = transform; 
            target.gameObject.name = target.TrackableName;

            target.gameObject.AddComponent<PlaneManager>();

            Debug.Log(target.TrackableName + " created!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
target.gameObject.transform.parent = transform;
```

That code means that the target gameObject will be a child of whatever gameObject the TargetManager script is attached to.

As derHugo pointed out in the comments, it's redundant and can just be written as

```
target.transform.parent = transform;
```

Comment: The target manager is just under the "SampleScene"... So it has no parent ?

Comment: No, the target manager has no parent. But we're not talking about the target manager. We're talking about the individual targets themselves. Those will be children of the target manager.

Comment: Oh yes ok! so any transform applied to the target manager it will affect the kids ?

Comment: Correct. You can test this out in the editor. You can make one object a child of another. Then, as you move, rotate or scale the parent, the child will adjust accordingly.

Comment: In simple it just means that `target` will be a child of `TargetManager`. It's a bit redundant though: `target.transform.parent =...` would be enough ;)